# How to show full tag name in `adb logcat`?

Tags: android, adb

Just as the title, how to show full tag name in `adb logcat`?

Because some tags are too long that the `adb logcat` truncated the tag. You can see the beginning of tags are replaced with `...` when they are too long. And I want to filter out those message based on tag so I need the full tag.

```
I/...ftcomm/MachineNumber: MAP Client side on
I/...e.LocalKeyValueStore: Create account with number: 
D/...oftAccountManager[0]: MAP Accounts number:
D/...oftAccountManager[0]: MAP Accounts number:
E/...oreSecurityHelper[0]: pid 1318 could not be found
D/...tedRequestHandler[0]: Unknown (1318) wants to use device credentials to
D/...oftAccountManager[0]: MAP Accounts number:
D/...oftAccountManager[0]: MAP Accounts number:
D/...tiableDataStorage[0]: Get user data for:
```

I have tried `adb logcat -v long` / `adb logcat -v tag` and they all show the truncated tags.

Comment: I don't think those messages are truncated by logcat. For example if I execute regular `adb logcat` and then in a second shell execute `adb shell log -t my_taaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaag "message"` then the tag is fully displayed.